# Javascript call object methods from array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, inheritance, methods, overriding

I am trying to loop through an array of gameobjects and call their update methods.
Gameobjects can have different update implementations (eg: update of enemy is different from update of friend), so I created an prototype inheritance chain. But I can't get it to work: while looping through all objects I don't seem to be able to call their update methods: the compiler says they don't exist. So my question is: is it possible in Javascript to loop trough an array of objects that share the same base class and call a method on them that can be overwritten by different sub-classes?

This is what I have so far, don't know where I went wrong...:

```
//base gameobject class 
function GameObject(name) {
    this.name = name
};
GameObject.prototype.update = function(deltaTime) {
    throw new Error("can't call abstract method!")
};

//enemy inherits from gameobject
function Enemy() {
    GameObject.apply(this, arguments)
};
Enemy.prototype = new GameObject();
Enemy.prototype.constructor = Enemy;
Enemy.prototype.update = function(deltaTime) {
    alert("In update of Enemy " + this.name);
};


var gameobjects = new Array();

// add enemy to array
gameobjects[gameobjects.length] = new Enemy("weirdenemy");

// this doesn't work: says 'gameobject doesn't have update method'
for (gameobject in gameobjects) {
    gameobject.update(1); // doesn't work!!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not a problem with your Inheritance chain, but with this construct

```
for(gameobject in gameobjects){
    gameobject.update(1); // doesn't work!!
}
```

When you iterate an `Array` with `for..in`, the variable will have the index values only. So, `gameobject` will have `0`, `1`.. like that, in every iteration. [It is not recommended to use `for..in` to iterate an Array.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in)

You might want to use, [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), like this

```
gameobjects.forEach(function(gameObject) {
    gameObject.update(1);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I was looking for the problem in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate through an array with `for ... in`, the values of the loop variable will be the **keys** to the array, not the values.

You really shouldn't iterate through arrays that way anyway:

```
for (var i = 0; i < gameobjects.length; ++i)
    gameobjects[i].update(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me: =)

```
 gameobjects.forEach(function(gameobject){
        gameobject.update(1); // doesn't work!!
    });
```